# Check combinations of enums in a list (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, enums

I have a list of enums, and I want to check for combinations of these and for single enums if they are present. Some errors have higher precedence than others. My current solution is this:

```kotlin
enum class ErrorCode {
    TECHNICAL_ERROR,
    DOCUMENT_ERROR,
    SIGNATURE_ERROR,
    MAGIC_ERROR,
}

fun main() {
    val errorList: List<ErrorCode> = listOf(
        ErrorCode.DOCUMENT_ERROR,
        ErrorCode.SIGNATURE_ERROR,
        ErrorCode.MAGIC_ERROR,
    )
 
    when {
        errorList.contains(ErrorCode.TECHNICAL_ERROR) -> println("Techincal Error")
        errorList.containsAll(listOf(ErrorCode.DOCUMENT_ERROR, ErrorCode.SIGNATURE_ERROR)) 
            -> println("Document and Signature Error")
        errorList.contains(ErrorCode.DOCUMENT_ERROR) -> println("Document Error")
        errorList.contains(ErrorCode.SIGNATURE_ERROR) -> println("Signature Error")
        else -> println("No Errors")
    }
}
```

There is also a problem that I don't get any help from the compiler with handling the enums as I would if it wasn't in a list. But then I don't know how to check for combinations. For example this would help me writing a case for every enum:

```kotlin
val error: ErrorCode = ErrorCode.TECHNICAL_ERROR

when (error) {
    ErrorCode.TECHNICAL_ERROR -> println("Technical Error")
    ...
    ErrorCode.MAGIC_ERROR -> println("Magic Error")
    else -> println("No Errors")
}
```

What would be a better solution for checking combinations of an enum?

Comment: I don't see how the compiler could possibly help you with this, because how could it know which combinations you want to test and in what order, and tell you if you're missing one of them? It would have to read your mind.

Comment: Bad explanation on my part. I meant that it would tell me if when I added a new ErrorCode that I didn't make a case for it in the `when`.

Comment: @Rockyy you can get that compiler check by using a sealed class/interface and child classes instead of an enum, those have all child classes defined at compile time, so when you do a when{} the compiler will complain if not all options are handled, assuming you don't have an else option (which will slurp up the error as it's a catch all). https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html#sealed-classes-and-when-expression

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you want to happen with regards to higher precedence and on what it is based, but I assume you only want to print the most important error, or all the errors of equal importance if multiple. And are ok with defining the importance of the errors in the enum instances.

Something like this would then work.

```
enum class ErrorCode(val printStr: String, val importance: Int) {
    TECHNICAL_ERROR("Technical", 10),
    DOCUMENT_ERROR("Document", 5),
    SIGNATURE_ERROR("Signature", 5),
    MAGIC_ERROR("Magic", 0)
}
fun printErrors(errorList: List<ErrorCode>){
    if (errorList.isEmpty()){
        println("No Errors")
    } else {
        val highestImportance = errorList.maxOf { it.importance }
        val mostImportantErrors = errorList.filter{ it.importance == highestImportance }.map{ it.printStr }
        println(mostImportantErrors.joinToString(" and ") + " Error")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I only want what I define as the most important error print. It doesn't have to print though, it could be any random function I want to happen if the error hits. I'm not sure if I am ok with defining the importance in the enum instances, because if I were to add 5 more enum instances managing the importance with different combinations could be difficult.

Comment: It could be difficult, but it would be much less difficult than managing switch branches in various when statements all over your project.